# room/timeslot schedule optimization

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

People can chose up to 5 of 25 lectures in advance. All these lectures are given on one day in five rooms at five time slots. Each (preferred) lecture a listener can attend to makes her a bit happier, each lecture he chose but can't attend to (because another preferred lecture is in the same time slot) makes him a bit unhappier. The list of preferred lectures is not weighted (at least the registrants have not been told to order their preferences, but if it makes things easier I could assume that the first choice has the highest priority and so on, that information is available).
Is there a way to maximize the overall happiness or an approximation without trying every single possible schedule? I've found an empty stub for the hospitals/residents problem on wikipedia which pretty much sounds like a similar problem(?)

> [The hospitals/residents problem — also known as the college admissions problem — differs from the stable marriage problem in that the "women" can accept "proposals" from more than one "man" (e.g., a hospital can take multiple residents, or a college can take an incoming class of more than one student). Algorithms to solve the hospitals/residents problem can be hospital-oriented (female-optimal) or resident-oriented (male-optimal).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem)

Comment: In the real world there are additional constraints: Can all lecturers give their lectures during all time slots? Are any two or more lectures given by the same lecturer, again eliminating possible combinations? Room capacity?

Comment: Since I'm only looking for a direction, a "name" or a similar solution I currently don't care about additional constraints. It can easily be done by brute force, but if there's a more elegant way I would like to know, like "yeah, that's exactly a xyz-problem usually solved by Joe-Schmoe-procedure"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've provided all of the information. If you have 25 total lectures (assuming no duplicates, as that wasn't described) with 5 time slots and 5 rooms then there are always going to be 4 lectures missed at every slot by any given attendee. Given that you haven't provided any capacity restrictions on the lectures and you explicitly said they aren't weighted, there is no difference in aggregate (or even personal) happiness between everyone attending the same lecture ordistributing the attendees (evenly or unevenly) over all 5 concurrent lectures.

Comment: The question does not limit the number of rooms. Without that restriction, 14 lectures could be in Slot A and only 3 lectures in Slot B to facilitate maximizing the attendees enjoyment.

Comment: "People can chose up to 5 of 25 lectures." Therefore there's noneed for them to always miss 4 lectures. All their preferred 5 lectures are in different time slots and they are perfectly happy. All their preferred lectures are in one time slot and they are very sad and won't attend at all.

Comment: "The question does not limit the number of rooms. Without that restriction," Wrong. "All these lectures are given on one day in five rooms" There are only five rooms. 5 rooms, 5 time slots, 25 lectures, all rooms occupied at any given time slots (maybe unless no one wants this lecture, ignore that)

Comment: @chendral: OK, gotcha. That portion of it wasn't clear (to me, which may mean nothing!) in the question. They aren't made "sad" by the fact that a lecture is taking place that they aren't in, they're "sad" if one of their PREFERRED lectures is going on and they can't attend.